# Identify Burt's gun in Tremors 2

Tags: tremors-ii-aftershocks

In [Tremors 2: Aftershocks](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114720/), there's a scene where Burt shoots a shrieker with a large gun/rifle, the shot goes through the shrieker, through the wall behind it, through a shed and into a truck's engine.

Can anyone identify the make/model of the gun?

Comment: Wait answered the question perfectly, but I remember Burt actually referring to his gun by name in the movie. If you watch the movie again I'm pretty sure he calls it his "Grizzly Big Boar"

Comment: A film-themed exchange where Identifying movies is off-topic but identifying guns is not. How very American!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, we're mostly movie experts, not gun experts, but [according to the IMFDb](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Tremors_2:_Aftershocks) (the Internet Movie Firearm Database), it's a [LAR Grizzly Big Boar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grizzly_Big_Boar).

[image]

Comment: And BTW, if you ever need to ID a *car* in a movie, the [IMCDb](http://www.imcdb.org/) (Internet Movie Cars Database) is another helpful tool.

Answer (score -2):

.50 caliber ..same caliber used in World War 2 U.S. fighter planes and still used in fighter jets..legal own. (check by state ) used for anti aircraft machine guns..single and quad truck turret mounted..different projectiles are ..standard. .armour piercing. .tracer ( phosphorus )..incinderary..armour piercing explosive. .rifle used by many military snipers..[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about the gun. This question already had the correct, and accepted answer as well.